# Python 3 Tkinter - Disabling buttons out of order code

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter

Currently I am attempting to disable certain buttons in my UI when a certain condition is met. The only problem is I can only change the state of a button after it is created.

I made a `Disabler` class to handle this for me but getting it to run is proving difficult. The disabler, if I get it to work, will have the task of disabling all buttons to do with my timer class so the user knows that they are not clickable (or they do not do anything).

Below is a cut down version of my code only showing the buttons.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class StopWatch(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        StopWatch.on = 1
        TimeAdjustLabel = LabelFrame(root, text='Frame',)
        TimeAdjustLabel.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        StopWatch.b1 = Button(TimeAdjustLabel, text='Reset', width=10, command=self.Start)
        StopWatch.b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def Start(self, event=None):
        if StopWatch.on == 0:
            StopWatch.on = 1
        else: 
            StopWatch.on = 0
        self.enable()

    def enable(self):
        if StopWatch.on == 0:
            StopWatch.b1.configure(state=DISABLED)
        else: 
            StopWatch.b1.configure(state=NORMAL)


def main():
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why have you created a class for disabling?Just a method would have sufficed...don't you think?

Comment: Indeed it would have. How would I make it work though? Can you run the method directly from the Stopwatch class?

Comment: put the button & the labelframe inside the stopwatch class & then use `self`

Comment: I updated the question above, am I on the right track? how do I make `self.enable()` look for the `def` below and not in the `Stopwatch` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.You will understand the minute you see it.What I was trying to tell you is this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class StopWatch(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.on = 1
        TimeAdjustLabel = LabelFrame(root, text='Frame',)
        TimeAdjustLabel.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.b1 = Button(TimeAdjustLabel, text='Reset', width=10, command=lambda:self.Start(self.on))
        self.b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def Start(self, onoff):
        if onoff == 0:
            onoff = 1
        else: 
            onoff = 0
        self.enable(onoff)


    def enable(self,enableonoff):
        if enableonoff == 0:
            self.b1.configure(state='disabled')
        else: 
            self.b1.configure(state='normal')

def main():
    app = StopWatch(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks for that. I have a few minor problems but I should be able to work the rest out by myself.